# how to set compile time validation on class instance members

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I have created a class like below:

```
class myclass
{
  Public  int myint;
}
```

Now I want to restrict the range of myint(min 5 and max 10).

I want if any one set the value of  myint which is not in the range it will give a compile time error(not runtime error)
please help me how to achive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's experimental, but you could look into [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/).  It can provide you with more compile-time checks.  Code Contracts are another option (but that's only available in certain editions of Visual Studio).

**Edit:**

Looks like code contacts may now be available as a standalone download!  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992)!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that out-of-the-box in .NET, but there're some validation engines that let you validate an instance of some object against some rules.

Read about:

- NHValidator: It can be used standalone, read this article: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/01/nhibernate-validator.aspx
- Microsoft Application Validation Block: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650484.aspx

I'll suggest you to use NHValidator, because it's very easy-to-use, needs zero configuration and it has a good community support. Another good point is you can use in any layer (business, presentation...) because it's attribute-oriented, meaning that you don't need to inherit any class or implement an interface in order to use it anywhere!

Comment: what do u mean by the following line                                       Another good point is you can use in any layer (business, presentation...) because it's attribute-oriented, meaning that you don't need to inherit any class or implement an interface in order to use it anywhere

Comment: i dont want to use nhibernate becoz its ment for database,send is microsoft enterprice lib well this gives u runtime error (not compile time error)

Comment: I mean that you can validate objects in any layer, because properties with validation rules are using attributes from a library that can be invoked from your business or presentation. Imagine that you need to validate that some object has the expected values before saving it to database, or you need to validate that some form filled by some user has its fields with right values. You can do both things with NHValidator.

Comment: It's not true. NHValidator works standalone. The only benefit for NHibernate is same validation attributes are used for auto-creating the database from your objects, but if you're not using NHibernate, NHValidator has no dependency to NHibernate.

Comment: is u r sure that nhibernate validation are compile time not run time

Comment: Well, it's not compile-time. Sure. You define validation rules with attributes for class properties, and these are evaluated run-time. But how you think compiler can validate without running the actual code?? :D